# Правильное использование единиц rem

Tags: html, css, шрифты

Допустим, я указываю все размеры шрифтов в `rem` единицах, далее я при определенном размере экрана задаю уменьшение шрифта, но выходит так, что шрифты, которые до этого уже были маленькими, стали еще меньше, до такой степени, что они более нечитабельны.

Вот пример:

```css
html {
  font-size: 10px;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 4rem;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 3rem;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
}

h4 {
  font-size: 2rem;
}

p {
  font-size: 1.4rem;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  html {
    font-size: 6px;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
  <h1>Simple text</h1>
  <h2>Simple text</h2>
  <h3>Simple text</h3>
  <h4>Simple text</h4>
  <p>Simple text</p>
</html>
```

Вопрос в том, что делать в таких случаях? Как правильно поступать? Для маленьких шрифтов задавать значения размера в абсолютных величинах?

Comment: Для маленьких шрифтов в @media задавать те величины rem, которые устраивают, или как Вы сказали в абсолютных писать. Просто проверять, что происходит и нравится ли результат.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Подходов для динамической типографики может быть много, я бы на вашем месте обратил внимание на возможности функции `calc()` и, может быть, на зависимость размера шрифта от ширины экрана — простейшая формула `font-size: calc(1rem + 1vw)`, с деталями коэффициентов надо уже экспериментировать. Также можете поинтересоваться темой CSS-шлюзов.

В вашем конкретном случае получается так, что вы задаете базовый размер шрифта 6 пикселей — потому естественно, что текст будет очень мелким. Вот пример, как этого частично можно избежать с применением функции `calc()` и цсс-переменных. Надо добавить увеличивающий коэффициент к тем значениям, которые становятся слишком мелкими на маленьких экранах, в то время как на больших оставить его равным единице.

```css
html {
  font-size: 10px;
  --font-ratio: 1;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 4rem;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 3rem;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
}

h4 {
  color: red;
  font-size: calc(2rem * var(--font-ratio));
}

p {
  color: red;
  font-size: calc(1.4rem * var(--font-ratio));
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  html {
    font-size: 6px;
    --font-ratio: 1.25;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
  <h1>Simple text</h1>
  <h2>Simple text</h2>
  <h3>Simple text</h3>
  <h4>Simple text</h4>
  <p>Simple text</p>
</html>
```

Comment: А если например, добавлять фикс размер мелким шрифтам, это неправильный подход?

Comment: В вашем случае, я бы просто избегал того, чтобы задавать такой мелкий базовый шрифт, 6 пикселей это слишком.